# dynamically add/remove style in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in any browser to add/remove class names? For example, if I have a div with class names  and I just want to remove/add 'name2' is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use jQuery:

to remove:

`$('#div1').removeClass('name2')`

to add:

`$('#div1').addClass('name2')`

If you can't use jQuery, I found this url

http://snipplr.com/view/3561/addclass-removeclass-hasclass/

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
    if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
        var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
        ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
}
```

Honestly, I haven't used the non-jquery approach but it seems enough

Answer (score 3):

There *will* be a standard way to do this. HTML5 introduces the [classList](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#domtokenlist) property, which works like this:

```
element.classList.add('foo');
element.classList.remove('bar');
if (element.classList.contains('bof'))
    element.classList.toggle('zot');
```

Firefox 3.6 already has this feature and it's being worked on in WebKit.

Here is a pure-JS implementation:

```
// HTML5 classList-style methods
//
function Element_classList(element) {
    if ('classList' in element)
        return element.classList;

    return {
        item: function(ix) {
            return element.className.trim().split(/\s+/)[ix];
        },
        contains: function(name) {
            var classes= element.className.trim().split(/\s+/);
            return classes.indexOf(name)!==-1;
        },
        add: function(name) {
            var classes= element.className.trim().split(/\s+/);
            if (classes.indexOf(name)===-1) {
                classes.push(name);
                element.className= classes.join(' ');
            }
        },
        remove: function(name) {
            var classes= element.className.trim().split(/\s+/);
            var ix= classes.indexOf(name);
            if (ix!==-1) {
                classes.splice(ix, 1);
                element.className= classes.join(' ');
            }
        },
        toggle: function(name) {
            var classes= element.className.trim().split(/\s+/);
            var ix= classes.indexOf(name);
            if (ix!==-1)
                classes.splice(ix, 1);
            else
                classes.push(name);
            element.className= classes.join(' ');
        }
    };
}

// Add ECMA262-5 string trim if not supported natively
//
if (!('trim' in String.prototype)) {
    String.prototype.trim= function() {
        return this.replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    };
}

// Add ECMA262-5 Array indexOf if not supported natively
//
if (!('indexOf' in Array.prototype)) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf= function(find, from /*opt*/) {
        for (var i= from || 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
            if (i in this && this[i]===find)
                return i;
        return -1;
    };
}
```

This does mean you have to write:

```
Element_classList(element).add('foo');
```

which is slightly less nice, but you'll get the advantage of the fast native implementation where avaialble.

Comment: You could have just do element.classList.add('foo'), .remove('foo'), and toggle('foo') directly on the classList object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList

Comment: Errrm... yes, that's the exact same object specified by the W3 doc I linked. :-) The problem is support for legacy browsers, hence the above polyfill code.

Answer (score 1):

its easy with javascript to change class name with any event for eg.

```
<script>
function changeClas()
{
    document.getElementById('myDiv').className='myNewClass';
}    
</script>

<div id="myDiv" onmouseover='changeClas()' class='myOldClass'> Hi There</div>
```