# How to add and remove style component on the fly by javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [dynamically add/remove style in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578577/dynamically-add-remove-style-in-javascript)

It's required to write javascript functions to disable and enable selection of the element. I wrote sample code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.selectable {
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
</style>
<script>
function makeUnselectable(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 1) {
    node.unselectable = true;
  }
  var child = node.firstChild;
  while (child) {
    makeUnselectable(child);
    child = child.nextSibling;
  }
}
function makeSelectable(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 1) {
    node.unselectable = false;
  }
  var child = node.firstChild;
  while (child) {
    makeSelectable(child);
    child = child.nextSibling;
  }
}
</script>
```

But this code is incorrect and doesn't work. How to add and remove style component on the fly by javascript? All the current element's styles and the class should remain!

Comment: http://rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Comment: @raina77ow I think that is what the OP is actually attempting.

Comment: > Erm... if you're using classes, why not just add/remove a class then? - I have a huge page with a lot of styles and should only control selection on it.

Comment: > rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript - Will it add a several classes to the element without replacing them?

Comment: But of course, it will. ) Don't you see that it checks for existence of its argument in the element's `className`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will be correct:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    .unselectable {
      -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
  }
  function addClass(ele,cls) {
    if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
  }
  function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
      var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
      ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
    }
  }
  function makeUnselectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      addClass(node, "unselectable");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
      makeUnselectable(child);
      child = child.nextSibling;
    }
  }
  function makeSelectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
      removeClass(node, "unselectable");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
      makeSelectable(child);
      child = child.nextSibling;
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Thanks to: [rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript](http://rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript)

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `hasClass` function and a link to Jake's article: http://rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

you can use Jquery
Take a look to the css method: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: No, [you don't have to use jQuery](http://rockycode.com/blog/addremove-classes-raw-javascript/).

Comment: No you don't have to use jQuery. It can be done in pure JavaScript.

Comment: yes right, I correct my answer to "you can use" jquery ^_^

Comment: If you read the OP's code above, it attempts to toggle CSS _classes_ on and off. `jQuery.css()` does not handle that use case - it can only modify CSS properties individually.